# How to apply transform effect to box-shadow only

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element, pseudo-class, box-shadow

I'm building a menu that uses the :hover pseudo classes to display a box-shadow.

[Here's a nav item as normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrcGH.png) and [here's the same item under :hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVlnY.png).

I'm using the transform property to apply a skew to the box-shadow, so that it looks like a chunky, overlapping, slanted underline.

```
.link:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 -0.5em 0 #7ed6df inset;
    transform: skew(-20deg);
}
```

As you can see, the skew works, but it also skews the .link text when I only want the box-shadow to be skewed.

I tried to create a parent style with @apply like so:

```
--link-underline: {
    box-shadow: 0 -0.5em 0 #7ed6df inset;
    transform: skew(-20deg);
}

...

.link:hover {
    @apply --link-underline;
}
```

but there was no change when I hovered over the link, and I toyed with an ::after pseudo element that added the shadow to an invisible text element, but couldn't find a fix that worked there either. I would be so grateful for any advice. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After fiddling with pseudo elements and classes more, I have a [working solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZFnA.png)!

First I added these two properties to my original .link class, making sure the text was stabilised:

```
display: inline;
position: relative;
```

Then I created an ::after pseudo element for my .link class:

```
.link::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 -0.5em 0 #7ed6df inset;
    transform: skew(-20deg);
    opacity: 0;
}
```

This element uses the z-index to sit underneath the original text, and hides itself with 0 opacity. The box shadow and the skew are applied to this ::after element, but because its content is empty, no text is affected. All I needed to do then was add the :hover function, which puts the pseudo class onto 1 opacity:

```
.link:hover::after {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Thank you for the suggestions, I wanted to use box-shadow for this as I am trying to animate a swiping motion too.

Answer (score 0):

I gave this a try and I've kinda achieved what you wanted but I'm not sure if this is the best solution but this kinda works. You can change the value of `top: 11%;` to adjust the position if it changes in your browser. Hope this helps you in some way.

```css
hr.underline {
  border: 5px solid #7ed6df;
  transform: skew(-20deg);
  display: none;
}

.hover:hover .underline{
    display: flex;
    width: 5%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 11%;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="hover">
  <h3 class="link">Why</h3>
  <hr class="underline">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for giving it a go! Unfortunately your solution isn't very responsive, I'm looking for something that works well with Flexbox in CSS3 and can be used on multiple screen sizes. If you look on 'full page' of the code snippet above you'll see that it falls apart pretty quickly. But thank you so much for giving it a shot!

Comment: Oh hey, your welcome. Sorry my answer wasn't helpful. Hope you find a solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea using multiple background:

```css
.text {
  display:inline-block;
  padding:5px 10px 5px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(-225deg,transparent 10px,lightblue 10px) bottom left /51% 15px,
    linear-gradient(-45deg ,transparent 10px,lightblue 10px) bottom right/51% 15px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  
  
  
/*the below is not relevant, can be removed if hover is not needed*/
  background-size:0 0;
}
.text:hover {
  background-size:51% 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">some text here</div>
<div class="text">text</div>
<br>
<div class="text">loooooooooooooooooooong text</div>
```